# Java how to get and show simple data

Tags: java

I need to get data and show it.

This is my question

```
Construct a class designed to perform that takes student record containing Roll Number, Name and Marks
as data and functions like get()and show() to take input in data and display data.
```

I am trying to do like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student {
    String name;
    String stu_id;
    int score;
    public Student() {
        this(" ", " ", 0);
    }
    public Student(String initName, String initId, int initScore) {
        name = initName;
        stu_id = initId;
        score = initScore;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input number of students:");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
        System.out.println("Input Student Name, ID, Score:");
        Student stu = new Student();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
            stu.name = in.next();
            stu.stu_id = in.next();
            stu.score = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(stu.name + " " + stu.stu_id);

        }
        System.out.println("name, ID of the highest score and the lowest score:");
        System.out.println(stu.name + " " + stu.stu_id);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

But its wrong I just need to create a function show() on which ill get data and from get() function it will just print

Comment: As per the question given, You need to create 2 functions. `get()` for taking the data from user, but you are taking it from `main()` body and `show()` for displaying those data.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this solution is acceptable, you will try to rewrite it later from memory, this is how I began to learn to program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student {
    String name;
    String stu_id;
    int score;

    public Student() {
        this("None", "None", 0);
    }

    public Student(String initName, String initId, int initScore) {
        name = initName;
        stu_id = initId;
        score = initScore;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", stu_id='" + stu_id + '\'' +
                ", score=" + score +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static Student get(Scanner in) {
        System.out.println("Input Student Name, ID, Score:");
        String name = in.next();
        int score = in.nextInt();
        String stu_id = in.next();
        return new Student(name, stu_id, score);
    }

    public static void show(Student student) {
        System.out.println(student);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input number of students:");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());

        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
            Student stu = get(in);
            studentList.add(stu);
        }

        studentList.forEach(student -> {show(student);});
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student {
    String name;
    String stu_id;
    int score;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void get()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Student Name, ID, Score:");
        name = in.nextLine();
        stu_id = in.nextLine();
        score = in.nextInt();
    }
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Name: "+name+"\nId: "+stu_id+"\nScore: "+score);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input number of students:");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        Student[] stu = new Student[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            stu[i] = new Student();
            stu[i].get();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            stu[i].show();
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply can you please give answer with main funcion running ? it will be very helpful

Comment: @rameezkhan done. do check if you can improve it any further.